# mariadb problem in specifying unicode data directory in create table statement

Tags: mariadb

i am using mariadb 10.4.12 x64 on windows 10

when executing: create table testtable (testfield int) data directory 'd:\البيانات';
to store table data file in a specific directory
mariadb created a folder named "d:\ط¨ظٹط§ظ†ط§طھظٹ" instead, and stored data files in it and every thing is working, the problem only in the folder name

when using english name every thing work fine

Comment: Welcome to DBA StackExchange. [10.4.12](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-104-series/) is 3.5 years old with lot of bug fixes already done. That said I searched and couldn't find a record of this bug being fixed, so [please create a bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).